# CachedNetworkImage throwing error after upgrading to latest Flutter Stable version

Tags: flutter

I upgraded Flutter today to version `v1.12.13` but when I run the app, I get the following error -

```
Compiler message:
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
^
../../flutter_src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_image_picker-4.5.9/lib/src/asset_thumb_provider.dart:31:24: Error: The method 'AssetThumbImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
ImageStreamCompleter load(AssetThumbImageProvider key) {
^
../../flutter_src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I am using the latest version of `CachedNetworkImageProvider`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently looks like an active [issue](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/301). Changing the version to `2.0.0-rc` fixes the error for time being.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [official page](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image#-readme-tab-)

> Breaking change with ImageProvider.load in Flutter 1.10
>
> The Flutter team made a breaking change with the ImageProvider in Flutter 1.10.15 (currently Master channel only).
>
> If you are experiencing one of the following errors upgrade to 2.0.0-rc.

switch to [cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/versions/2.0.0-rc#-installing-tab-)

If the issue still persists then try `flutter clean` and run.